# mongo db.find not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following script that I'm running through mongo shell. The first posts query executes fine and I receive the data object.  Also if I print the date after the convertDate function, the correct date is returned.  However in the second postdata findOne function I can't get any of the print statements to show anything. So there isn't an error but no results are found which should still show 'no record'.  Am I missing something here?

```
db.posts.find().forEach(function(data) {

var date = convertDate(data.created_at);

  db.postdata.findOne({ company_id: data.company_id, date: date }, function(err, post){
    if (err) { print('err' + err) }
    if(post){
        print('test' + post);
    } else {
        print('no record');
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: will you provide sample JSON data of posts and postdata ? What  convertDate is doing ?@user2383628

Comment: {
 "company_id" : ObjectId("50568d9a0071a17a6d000008"),
 "user_id" : "0",
 "_id" : ObjectId("5057aec21cb1d4c19b000698"),
 "created_at" : ISODate("2012-09-17T23:14:10.442Z")
}

Comment: convert date converts the date into the same format it is stored in the database

Answer (score 1):

`findOne` in the shell is synchronous so the found post is returned rather than passed into a callback.

```
db.posts.find().forEach(function(data) {
  var date = convertDate(data.created_at);
  var post = db.postdata.findOne({ company_id: data.company_id, date: date });
  if(post){
    print('test' + post);
  } else {
    print('no record');
  }
});
```